# Android Studio 1.5 | Creating Local Git

Tags: git, android-studio

I have searched a lot and viewed a lot of answers with no luck. I am using **Android Studio 1.5**.

Here is what I have done:

1. VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository...
   [image]
2. I created a directory "Git Repo".
3. I selected the root "app" directory.
4. VCS > Git > Checkin Directory...
   [image]
5. I receive Nothing to Commit (No changes detected).
   [image]
6. I modified one file. I still receive Nothing to Commit.

This is one of the times where 3 hours are wasted by an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, writing the question down reveals the answer :) I removed the repo directory I created and started all over. This time I selected VCS > Enable Version Control Integration. The repo folder **MUST** be created within the project folder not any external folder. Now everything is fine.

Comment: Yep, that's how Git works. It puts a .git folder at the root level of your project folder.